# Translate Taxonomy menu items

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary that I want to shows as menu. For this, I installed the taxonomy menu module and edit the vocabulary to hang from a menu item of Main Menu. The menu is shown perfectly.

The problem goes when I localize the terms of vocabulary, the menu is only shown in a default language. I have tried to rebuild the menu (by checking the "Select to rebuild the menu on submit." on vocabulary edit page and submitting), but the problem persists.

Comment: did you find a solution for the problem?

Comment: Taxonomy menu has no i18n integration. See http://drupal.org/node/1798700. So a solution for this problem passes by writing such an integration, or perhaps some custom code.

Answer (score 2):

[Entity translation](https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation)

> Allows (fieldable) entities to be translated into different languages, by introducing entity/field translation for the new translatable fields capability in Drupal 7. Maintained by the Drupal core i18n team.

together with Title module - (making the taxonmy terms translatable)

[Title module](https://drupal.org/project/Title)

> After enabling the module as usual, visit the Manage fields page of the content type, taxonomy vocabulary or "comment type" which you wish to replace fields of and click the replace link. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can:
1) Install Entity translation and enable taxonomy term in TRANSLATABLE ENTITY TYPES (admin/config/regional/entity_translation).

2) Install Title and (admin/structure/taxonomy/YOUR_VOCABULARY/fields) make "replace" title with title field.

3) Enable "Translate and Localize" option in your menu settings.

4) Install [Taxonomy menu dev release](http://www.drupal.org/node/1794894).

5) Apply patch [drupal.org/node/1665308](https://www.drupal.org/node/1665308#comment-9204915).

6) Rebuild your taxonomy menu.